# Child process needs to seteuid to root, parent does not

Tags: c, linux, exec, setuid

I'm writing a program that users can call to mount directories in / using sshfs. Here's the basic layout, with error handling and boilerplate omitted:

```
uid_t euid, ruid;

void mountDir(char *dirname, char *hostname){
    childPid = fork();
    if(childPid == 0){ 
        char *sshfsArgs[6] = {"/usr/bin/sshfs", hostName, /*Other args*/};
        seteuid(euid);
        execv(sshfsArgs[0], sshfsArgs);
        //I want to drop my setuid permissions with seteuid(ruid),
        //but execv doesn't return. 
    }else{ //I'm the parent process. 
        //I don't want to have root permissions now. 
        wait(childPid);
    }
}


void main(int argc, char **argv){
    ruid = getuid();
    euid = geteuid();
    seteuid(ruid); //Drop the root permissions. 
    char **hostList = {"bulb.example.com", "char.example.com", argv[1]};
    char * hostName = pickHost(hostList); //Pings them and picks one that responds.
    mountDir("/net/home", hostName);
    mountDir("/net/projects", hostName);
}
```

Again, copious error checking omitted. I want to have root permissions only when running `sshfs`. There are several examples out there of dropping `seteuid` privileges before calling `fork()`, but here I want to gain them only in the child process, and lose them right after `execv`. How do I do this safely? What happens when a child process does a `seteuid` to root? Does the parent process ever get root privileges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are handling this now is correct.

The first thing the process does is drop root privileges, so it's safe at that point.

After the `fork`, the parent waits for the child and the child runs `seteuid(euid);`.  So the child is now running with root privileges (since that is where `seteuid` is run) but the parent is not.  The child then calls `execv` to run `sshfs` with root privileges.

The `seteuid` call in the child does not affect the parent because they are  separate processes (even though they are running the same code prior to the `execv`).

Since `execv` does not return, there is no need to drop privileges again.  When `sshfs` finishes, that process ends.  If `execv` fails, then you would drop privileges and print an error messages before calling `_exit`.